# Ignore class in Hibernate entity mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity

Is it possibile to not create a table for class in the middle of entities hierarchy in Hibernate?

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BaseObject {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class SubtypeA extends BaseObject {
    ...
}

//@Entity <---- NOT AN ENTITY
public class SubtypeB extends BaseObject {
   ...
}

@Entity <---- ENTITY
public class SubtypeC extends SubtypeB {
   ...
}
```

I want to indicate that some entities are a subset of some type in order to return collection of all these entities but I'm not going to put any extra attributes in this intermediate type. Because of that it does not sound good to keep extra table with id field only to join the tables.

Better solution would be to implement some common interface `CommonInterface` but then I'm losing possiblity to return `List<CommonInterface>` list from the queries.

Comment: No that's not possible

Comment: I think too that it is not possible. If Hibernate allowed you to switch inheritance mapping strategy in the middle of an entity hierarchy, it could be possible to set it to TABLE_PER_CLASS in the SubtypeB, but (at least in v.5.4.x I tried) it does not. And JPA spec does not define the behavior for this. If the number of subtypes of SubtypeB are limited, you could do `SELECT x FROM BaseObject WHERE TYPE(x) IN (SubtypeC, SubtypeD)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact use case, but you can model `BaseObject` as `@MappedSuperclass` instead and let all types but `SubtypeB` extend a new class i.e. `BaseEntity`, which uses `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`.